# Python if statement confusing me

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Running python v3.6.5 PyCharm

### I have a simple for loop with an if and else statement with it:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i > 3 < 5:
        print(i, "first")
    else:
        print(i, "second")
```

### The output I get is:

```
0 second
1 second
2 second
3 second
4 first
5 first
6 first
7 first
8 first
9 first
```

### but shouldn't the output be:

```
0 second
1 second
2 second
3 second
4 first
5 second
6 second
7 second
8 second
9 second
```

Try it yourself. It doesn't make sense to me. Why is it doing this?

### **Don't really need to know**

I know you might be thinking, why didn't you just say

```
if i == 4
```

but this is just a simplified problem in my program.

Thanks in advance

Hugo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
if 3 < i < 5:
```

Be aware that Python is special here, and this construct won't work in most other languages (where you'd have to say something like `3 < i and i < 5` instead).

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks

Comment: That was quick, I was still reading the question :)

Comment: Is this syntax proper to python ?

Comment: @AntoineLB I was just editing that in :)

Comment: Yep ! Unlucky  ahah. thanks

Answer (score 7):

A chain of operators like `i > 3 < 5` is interpreted as

```
i > 3 and 3 < 5
```

where the "middle" operand(s) are repeated for the left and right operator. You want

```
3 < i and i < 5
```

, which can be abbreviated (using the reverse of the previous interpretation) as `3 < i < 5`.

Comment: You explained it in a better and appropriate way: i>3 and 3<5. My upvote for you.